# Is there Any alternate Command for puts in TCL

Tags: tcl

I was looking for alternate command for "puts".is there a alternate command for puts in tcl? if any please let me know

Comment: What do you expect this alternate command can do that `puts` can't? In other words, what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: No. If you redefined puts - choose another name. If you are in a namespace you can explicitly specify the global command using `::puts`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you just have `puts` and (from 8.5 onwards) `chan puts`, though that uses the *same* implementation code. But you can easily make your own commands to write things as you want. For example, here's a simple writer that insists on having a channel name and the data, configures the channel to work in binary mode, writes the data without a newline, and then flushes the channel:

```
proc writeBinary {channelName data} {
    fconfigure $channel -translation binary
    puts -nonewline $channelName $data
    flush $channelName
}
```

And here's something that works *very* much like C's `printf()`:

```
proc printf {pattern args} {
    puts [format $pattern {*}$args]
}
```

(I use more sophisticated versions of this adapted to logging, so that I can specify a logging level and the details of the message to write, and get the message logged to the appropriate log destination if enabled, in a manner reminiscent of Java's log4j. But you probably don't need that level of fanciness.)

*There's nothing wrong with writing a procedure to make things easier.* Tcl just provides `puts` as it turns out that's enough to build everything else.

Answer (score 1):

No, Tcl doesn't really have a bunch of different commands for output. Instead, different argument combinations and cooperation with other commands is used to produce output in different ways. For instance, `puts` can be modified to direct output somewhere else than `stdout` (by providing a *channel* argument) or to not end the output with a line break (by providing the `-nonewline` flag). Formatted output (like in C's `printf`) can be produced by applying `puts` to the output of `format`, like in

```
puts [format "My string is %s" foo]
# => My string is foo
```

(a variation that allows the output to be multilingual:)

```
# ... insert necessary initialization here ...
puts [::msgcat::mc "My string is %s" foo]
# => Min sträng är foo
```

So we usually make do. Is there anything in particular that you're looking for?